# Loading Game State with NSCoder?

Tags: load, cocos2d-iphone, save, nscoder

How can I load the items I saved (or tried to save) with NSCoder? I am using the cocos2d framework. Here's a method I made to save things.

```
-(void)save: (NSCoder *) coder {
    [coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:level]];    
    [coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:actualScore]];
    [coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:actualHp]];
    [coder encodeObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:bunnyArray]];
    [coder encodeObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:moleArray]];
}
```

I get warnings that Passing Argument 1 of 'numberWithInt' makes integer from pointer without a cast.

Comment: -(id)initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder {
 level = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kLevelKey];
 actualScore = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kScoreKey];
 actualHp = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kHealthKey];
 bunnyArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kBunnyArrayKey];
 moleArray = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kMoleArrayKey];     
 return decoder;
}

Answer (score 0):

Well, try

```
level = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:kLevelKey] intValue];
```

if type of level is int.